# Distinct Pairing of users of different groups using Sql

Tags: sql, algorithm, pairing

50 Users with a record format

- Id,
- Name,
- Group_Id

And Groups

```
1,
2,
3
```

Are to be inserted into a pairs table in the format

- Id,
- Pair_1,
- Pair_2

**Note**

Users belongs to different groups.

Users from group 2 cannot pair with each other and users from group 3 can also not pair with each other, duplicates must also be avoided.

How do i go about this in Sql. Am a novice.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help, as would an appropriate database tag.  You have columns called `pair_1` and `pair_2` but you explain nowhere what these are.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample data in Javascript
[
{
Id:1,
Name:"James",
Group_Id:3
},
{
Id:2,
Name:"Daniel",
Group_Id:3
},
{
Id:3,
Name:"Jonathan",
Group_Id:2
},
{
Id:4,
Name:"Esther",
Group_Id:1
},
{
Id:5,
Name:"Leo",
Group_Id:1
}
]

Pair_1 & Pair_2 are two paired users to be added to a pairs table based on the condition explained earlier.